# Java - Result when compare two ZonedDateTime is not as expected

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

I have this code :

```
ZonedDateTime t1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-04-06T10:01:00.000+03:00");
ZonedDateTime t2 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-04-06T10:01:00.000-03:00");
System.out.println(t1.compareTo(t2));
```

The result is -1. I guess it will convert both t1 and t2 to the same timezone then compare it. E.g in the first case it will (maybe) compare

```
t1 = 2018-04-06T07:01:00.000+00:00 to t2 = 2018-04-06T13:01:00.000+00:00
```

This case return 1 as I expected

```
ZonedDateTime t1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-04-06T17:01:00.000+03:00");
ZonedDateTime t2 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-04-06T10:01:00.000-03:00");
System.out.println(t1.compareTo(t2));
```

But this one (*) doesn't return 0, it return 1 :

```
ZonedDateTime t1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-04-06T16:01:00.000+03:00");
ZonedDateTime t2 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-04-06T10:01:00.000-03:00");
System.out.println(t1.compareTo(t2));
```

I even try to use `truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)` after parse the string to ignore the seconds part but nothing change.

The most interested thing is if I decrease / increase t1 / t2 by one second, the result will be -1

e.g :

```
ZonedDateTime t1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-04-06T16:01:00.000+03:00");
ZonedDateTime t2 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-04-06T10:01:01.000-03:00");
System.out.println(t1.compareTo(t2));
```

In my use case, all user input time will be saved in the above format in many ZoneOffset and I have some query where I need to compare it with server time (ignore the seconds of the time). How can I get t1 equals t2 in case (*) above?

Comment: Yes, the I might understand the first case. The case I don't understand is when I compare `2018-04-06T16:01:00+03:00` to `2018-04-06T10:01:00-03:00` it return 1, in this case they are equal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [toInstant()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toInstant--), then compare the results, like so:

```
    ZonedDateTime t1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-04-06T16:01:00.000+03:00");
    ZonedDateTime t2 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-04-06T10:01:00.000-03:00");
    System.out.println(t1.toInstant().compareTo(t2.toInstant()));
```

Comment: I apologise, and I have replaced my downvote with an upvote.  My comment was correct for the first part of hai_uit's question - but I didn't realise that hai_uit was more interested in other parts of the question.

Answer (score 25):

> The comparison is based first on the instant, then on the local
>   date-time, then on the zone ID, then on the chronology. It is
>   "consistent with equals", as defined by `Comparable`.

`compareTo` is implemented in the superclass [`ChronoZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#compareTo-java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime-), a class that we usually don’t care about, but where we need to look for the documentation of some of the methods. So the above quote comes from there.

So in the case where both `ZonedDateTime` objects denote the same instant, `t1`’s local time is 16:01, which is greater than the `t2`’s 10:01. So 1 is the correct and expected result. On the other hand, if the instants are just one second apart — or just 1 nanosecond — that takes precedence, and the local times are not compared.

I believe this explains the behaviour you observed.

The quote furthermore gives a hint as to why this must be so: Suppose that comparing two `ZonedDateTime` objects with same instant but different time zones returned 0. Then the comparison would no longer be consistent with equals. Which is considered a pretty nice property (though not required).

> The natural ordering for a class `C` is said to be *consistent with
>   equals* if and only if `e1.compareTo(e2) == 0` has the same boolean
>   value as `e1.equals(e2)` for every `e1` and `e2` of class `C`.

(Quoted from [`Comparable` interface documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html))

So if you wanted to compare just the instants, there are two options depending on what type you prefer for your result:

1. Use `isBefore`, `isAfter` or `isEqual`:

   ```
   ZonedDateTime t1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-04-06T16:01:00.000+03:00");
   ZonedDateTime t2 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-04-06T10:01:00.000-03:00");
   System.out.println(t1.isBefore(t2));
   System.out.println(t1.isAfter(t2));
   System.out.println(t1.isEqual(t2));
   ```

   Output:

> ```
> false
> false
> true
> ```

2. Use [the answer by Yoav Gur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49686367/5772882): explicitly compare the instants.

Comment: In my use case, compare two instants is more suitable because i'm writing a comparator for sorting, so I need compare result in integer.