# How to sort arraylist of ZonedDateTime in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, zoneddatetime

I am trying to create a messaging app in Android and I need to sort the messages according to their timestamps, which I created from a ZonedDateTime object. I was going to parse the timestamp strings with the formatter I used to re-create a ZonedDateTime object, but I need to be able to sort the arraylist of ZonedDateTime objects in chronological order. How can I do this?

Comment: Possibly related: [Java - Result when compare two ZonedDateTime is not as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686272/java-result-when-compare-two-zoneddatetime-is-not-as-expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sorted()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted.html) is the way to sort items in a list.

[`sort()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort.html) will sort a mutable list or array.

In the Kotlin documentation, there are allusions to sorting by a *natural order* which only means that the class needs to implement the `Comparable` interface. `ZonedDateTime` implements `ChronoZonedDateTime` which implements `Comparable` so these methods should work.