# comparison operators vs comparison methods for ZonedDateTime

Tags: kotlin, java-time, zoneddatetime

using <, >, and == is not always the same as using .isBefore, .isAfter and isEqual when comparing ZonedDateTimes as shown by the following example in Kotlin:

```kotlin
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.ZoneOffset

fun main() {
    val a = ZonedDateTime.of(2022, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Europe/Oslo"))
    val b = ZonedDateTime.of(2022, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC)
    println("a = $a")
    println("b = $b")
    println()
    println("a < b: ${a < b}")
    println("a > b: ${a > b}")
    println("a == b: ${a == b}")
    println()
    println("a.isBefore(b): ${a.isBefore(b)}")
    println("a.isAfter(b): ${a.isAfter(b)}")
    println("a.isEqual(b): ${a.isEqual(b)}")
}
```

Output:

```bash
a = 2022-01-01T13:00+01:00[Europe/Oslo]
b = 2022-01-01T12:00Z

a < b: false
a > b: true
a == b: false

a.isBefore(b): false
a.isAfter(b): false
a.isEqual(b): true
```

What is the difference?

Comment: I'd say it's the difference between [`isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#isEqual(java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime)) and [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

Comment: ...similarly the `isAfter()` method is specified to differ from `compareTo()` in a "subtle" way: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#isAfter(java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime): "This method differs from the comparison in `compareTo()` in that it only compares the instant of the date-time. This is equivalent to using `dateTime1.toInstant().isAfter(dateTime2.toInstant());`. "

Comment: Is this properly tagged as "Java"?

Comment: @tquadrat I just used kotlin in my example, but ZonedDateTime belongs to the java.time package and this question is just as relevant for someone using java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - Result when compare two ZonedDateTime is not as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686272/java-result-when-compare-two-zoneddatetime-is-not-as-expected)

Comment: @user3399023 – The answer by @Sweeper creates that relation to Java for this question. But as the operators <, >, and also == do not work for the comparison of instances of `ZonedDateTime` in Java, the *question itself* is purely Kotlin. (I know that == works in Java, but there it tests only for identity when used with objects, not for equality).

Comment: @tquadrat you're right, I just tested it and those operators does not work for ZDT in java. I thought they did. I'll remove the java-tag

Comment: @OleV.V. Maybe its the same question, I had some trouble understanding it so I'm not entirely sure. But I didn't know that `<`, `>`, `>=`, `<=` translate to `compareTo` so it wouldn't have helped me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operators `<`, `>`, `>=`, `<=` all translate to [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#compareTo(java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime)) calls, and `compareTo` does a subtly different thing from [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#isBefore(java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime)) and [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#isAfter(java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime)).

`compareTo`:

> Compares this date-time to another date-time, including the chronology.
> The comparison is based first on the instant, then on the local date-time, then on the zone ID, then on the chronology. It is "consistent with equals", as defined by `Comparable`.

`isBefore`:

> Checks if the instant of this date-time is before that of the specified date-time.

Basically, `compareTo` compares a lot more things. In other words, it has a lot more "tie-breakers". It even compares the chronology if it has to. On the other hand, `isBefore`/`isAfter` only compares the *instants* that the `ZonedDateTime`s represents.

The two dates in question, 2022-01-01T13:00+01:00[Europe/Oslo] and 2022-01-01T12:00Z represents the same instant in time, so `isBefore` and `isAfter` both return false. On the other hand, `compareTo` compares the *local* date times to break the tie. The local date time of 2022-01-01T13:00+01:00[Europe/Oslo] is later than that of 2022-01-01T12:00Z, so `compareTo` thinks the former is "bigger".

A similar distinction exists between `equals` (`==`) and `isEqual` - `equals` compares a lot more than `isEqual`.